# mongoDB Read preference issue

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

We operate a MongoDB replica set within an EKS cluster, consisting of one primary and two secondary nodes. The MongoDB server version is `3.4.10`, with the MongoDB shell version `v3.4.10`.

Our application, built using the NestJS framework, requires certain queries to execute on the secondary members. To achieve this, we attempted to use the following code snippet for an aggregate query:

> `aggregate(query).read('secondary').exec()`

However, during testing, we've encountered inconsistent behavior. Sometimes, the query logs appear on the primary member, and at other times, they don't appear on any of the three members. Can anyone provide insights into why this irregularity might be occurring?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `read` method in the shell, but readPreference option should be provided in the connection string

Comment: We tried giving the readPreference option in connection string. But the outcome was same.

Comment: ` the query logs appear on the primary member,` - what exactly do you mean here?

Comment: "Logs appear in primary member" means when you do "kubectl logs podname" you can see the logs of the POD.

Comment: what exactly do you see in the primary? The fact that you set readPreference=secondary doesn't  mean that primary does nothing this time

Comment: We can see the aggregate query in the logs.

Comment: you should provide more details: 1. Which connection string do you use. 2. Which exactly log do you see in the primary. 3. Try configure ApplicationName in the mongo client settings. With this option, this value will appear in the server logs and you will be able to know which client generated ongoing request

Comment: appName: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.appName, but it looks like it's supported started from server 4.0 though